# PDFBOX 1.8.10. Error in generating PDDocument from load() method

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using PDFBOX 1.8.10.

If I load the PDF File into byte array, it works -

```
File file = new File(args[0]);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);   //Normal PDF File
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
try {
    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
        bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
CheckIsPDF(bytes);
pdf = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)); //**No exception here**
```

But if the same file is stored in a database and If i try to read it through the above code, I get the following exception-
`"java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line"`.

This is the code to read from DB and populate the PDF-

```
List<byte[]> forms; //this gets populated from database. The data stored in DB is HEX.
for(byte[] file : forms){
    try{
        int var=file.length;

        pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(file)); //**Exception** 

        fieldLists = PDFFormUtils.printFields( pdDocument );

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please save one such byte array that results in an exception, and share it here for analysis.

Comment: "The data stored in DB is HEX" - does it mean that it is a hex string? In that case it must be converted to binary.  Please do also share the database storing / retrieval code. My bet is on that one :-)

Comment: The data is stored like this  `43  3a  5c  4d  42  43  50  4f  53  5c  52  65  6e  74  2e  70  64  66 `. This is basically the form data and I store it in DB as bytes.
The data type of the column is blob.

Comment: form data is not PDF. Pdf files begin with %PDF.

Comment: @Tilman I am uploading and storing the PDF file in DB. After storing the byte data (which looks like 43 3a ....) in DB (blob data type), I am trying to recreate the pdf. While recreating the PDF, in the PDDocument.load(bytes) i get IOException End-Of-File.

Comment: %PDF would be 25 50 44 46 in hex, not 43 3a 5c 4d.

Comment: the hex text from your comment converts to "C:\MBCPOS\Rent.pdf". So I guess somebody saved the file name instead of the file contents into the blob.

Comment: @Tilman. Yes figured that out. Now I am checking the code where the file is actually getting uploaded and if the bytes array are getting in the db. Can you write your above comment in answer so i can accept it and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the cause of the problem was that the content of the blob wasn't a PDF. The blob content is:

```
43 3a 5c 4d 42 43 50 4f 53 5c 52 65 6e 74 2e 70 64 66
```

A pdf starts with "%PDF", so in hex this would be

```
25 50 44 46
```

The hex sequence you mention translates to

```
C:\MBCPOS\Rent.pdf
```

which means that somebody saved the file name instead of the file contents into the blob.